# Can we connect to Exchange 2016 using EWS Managed API?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, exchange-server-2016

I am using EWS Managed API 2.2 and it does not show the Exchange version 2016 in its enumeration. I can see the versions upto Exchange 2013. So how can I connect to Exchange Server 2016? Is the API, yet to be updated from Microsoft or do I need to use any other API's to connect to Exchange 2016 ?

Answer (score 8):

It will connect just fine. You don't need to set the version to match the server, you set the version to indicate the lowest level of service you support.

Comment: Here is the scenario, I am trying to SubscribeToStreamingNotifications in Exchange 2016 by using the ExchangeVersion. If I use the ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013, will it work?

Comment: Should. Basically setting that sets the schema that's used to communicate. Exchange is backwards-compatible, so it supports the 2013 schema.

Comment: Thanks Jason, will test this and let u know