# ExchangeVersion for MS exchange server 2013 not found

Tags: java, exchange-server, ewsjavaapi, exchange-server-2013

In order to monitor an e-mail account on an MS exchange server 2013 , I am using ews-java-api version 2.0. I am facing one problem with this api. The status of the source code in GitHub says that [the api is outdated](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki#maven--gradle-integration). In fact, the source code of the ExchangeVersion enum does not include the latest versions 2013 & 2016 :

```
package microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc;

/**
 * Defines the each available Exchange release version.
 */
public enum ExchangeVersion {

  // / Microsoft Exchange 2007, Service Pack 1
  /**
   * The Exchange2007_ s p1.
   */
  Exchange2007_SP1,
  // / Microsoft Exchange 2010
  /**
   * The Exchange2010.
   */
  Exchange2010,

  /// Microsoft Exchange 2010, Service Pack 1
  /**
   * Exchange2010_SP1.
   */
  Exchange2010_SP1,

  // Microsoft Exchange 2010, Service Pack 2
  /**
   * Exchange2010_SP2.
   */
  Exchange2010_SP2,
}
```

How am I supposed to circumvent this issue? Should I drop the option of using ews-java-api and look for another alternative? If so what do you suggest please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here: [Can we connect to Exchange 2016 using EWS Managed API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774101/can-we-connect-to-exchange-2016-using-ews-managed-api)

According to that it should connect just fine with the value set to  Exchange2010_SP2.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!!

Answer (score 0):

That works for me as well on Exchange 2016. See the code below (firstname.lastname@domain.com) is my email address

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("firstname.lastname@domain.com", ews_password);
  global_exchange_service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
  global_exchange_service.setCredentials(credentials);
  global_exchange_service.setUrl(new URI(server_url));
```